# Java: Creating/Using an Array of Records

Tags: java, arrays, record

> I have an assignment that asks us to create a program to compute the dimensions (width and height) of a screen given the diagonal and aspect ratio.
>   I'm supposed to ask the user for the inputs (diagonal and aspect ratio), call a subprogram to compute the dimensions (height and width), then display the results. The subprogram needs to return both width and height, so I need to create a 'record' that combines the two into one unit. PLEASE HELP!
>
> - The formulas are:
>
>   - x = sqrt(y^2 / (1+ a^2))
>   - h=x
>   - w=ax
> - where:
>
>   - h=height
>   - w=width
>   - y=diagonal
>   - a=aspect ratio

Here's what I have so far: 
    package hw3;

```
//A. Nelson, a program to compute the dimensions (width & height)
//of a screen given the diagonal & aspect ratio

import java.util.Scanner;

class Screen
{
    public int height, width;
}

public class Hw3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Screen dimensions = new Screen();
    //Variables
    int yDiagonal, aAspect;
    //Program description
    System.out.println("This program will compute the dimensions (width and height)" +
            "\nof a screen given the diagonal and aspect ratio.");
    //Prompt 1: Diagonal
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the following dimensions:" +
            "\n\tDiagonal (inches): ");
    yDiagonal = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Prompt 2: Aspect
    System.out.print("\tAspect Ratio: ");
    aAspect = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Compute Dimensions
    System.out.println("\nHere are the dimensions of the screen:" +
            "\nHave a nice day!");

}

public Screen computeDimensions(int yDiagonal,int aAspect)
{

    int answer;

    answer = (int) Math.sqrt( Math.pow(yDiagonal,2) / (1+Math.pow(aAspect,2)));
    Screen [] dimensions = new Screen[2];
    Screen.height = answer;
    Screen.width = aAspect*answer;

    return Screen;
}

}
```

Comment: There is no call being made to the computeDimensions method.

Comment: "This is my homework assignment" is not a question.  It's a story.  And it's not even a good story.  Please come back when you have a _specific_ question about a _specific_ problem with _specific_ code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code

First, just declaring the method doesn't actually *invoke* the method (i.e. the method is never executed).  So at the end of your main method you need

```
dimensions = computeDimensions(yDiagonal, aAspect);
```

However, there are other serious issues.

First, you've declared `aAspect` as an integer, while screen aspect ratios normally have values that are NOT integer ratios, such as 1920x1080 or 16:9, which is 1.7777...  Same for other aspect ratios, so you'll need to accept a floating-point value instead of an integer, or write code to parse strings such as "16:9" and calculate the ratio.

Then inside `computeDimensions` you create an array of `Screen` objects, where you only need one.  The correct code here is

```
Screen result = new Screen();
result.height = answer;
result.width  = aAspect*answer;
return result;
```

and then in the main method *after* the call to `computeDimensions` you must print the values returned in `dimensions`.

There could be other problems as well in your definition of the algorithm.  I'm not going to write your entire assignment for you, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to Jim's right answer:

Here is an example on how to call the `computeDimensions` method from your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    //Compute Dimensions
    Screen s = computeDimensions(yDiagonal, aAspect);
    System.out.println("\nHere are the dimensions of the screen: height=" +
            s.height + ", width=" + s.width + "\nHave a nice day!");
}
```

Also, you have to add the keyword **`static`** to your `computeDimensions` method or the program won't compile, because you are calling from a static context:

```
public static Screen computeDimensions(int yDiagonal,int aAspect) {
    ...
}
```